# array incluyendo registros coincidentes y de relleno

Tags: php, php5, cakephp

Mediante un foreach obtengo el resultado de una consulta correspondiente a  1 solo día .. donde agrupo por el campo hora , de 0 a 23, y obtengo un count de los ingresos.
Necesito crear un nuevo array donde se guarden , de 0 a 23 , cada movimiento, completando los intermedios que no arrojan valores con 0 ó con valores predeterminados.

Como muestro mas abajo ... de la forma que pude hacer y no funciona ... hace 1 ciclo por cada registro , y eso genera que se reasignen las posiciones en cero y que solo quede guardado el registro de la ultima pasada.

```
foreach ($ingresos as $row) {
  $hora = intval(substr($row->hora, 0, 2));
  for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
  if ($row->hora >= 0 && $row->hora <= 6) {
    $fecha_prod = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($row->fecha));
    $fecha_prod = date('Y-m-d', $fecha_prod);
  } else {
    $fecha_prod = $row->fecha;
  }

  if ($hora == $i) {
    $data = [
      'fp' => $fecha_prod,
      'fecha' => $row->fecha,
      'hora' => $hora,
      'nuevos' => $row->ingresos,
      'cuenta' => $i . " = " . $hora
    ];
    var_dump($data);
  } else {
    $data = [
      'fp' => $row->fecha,
      'fecha' => $row->fecha,
      'hora' => $i,
      'nuevos' => $xx,
      'cuenta' => $i . " = " . $hora
    ];
    var_dump($data);
  }
}
```

Alguien que me pueda dar una mano ? Gracias

Me faltó una llave , al copiar quedó afuera. Los datos que recibo del resultado de la consulta, y que me llegan perfecto, serian  :

```
$row->fecha
$row->fecha
$row->hora
$row->nuevos // ( este es un count y llega bien el total )
```

Como aclaracion, los datos llegan bien , el problema es que al agregar cada registro a `$data = [ ]` ... estoy recorriendo `$i < 24` , o sea de 0 a 23. En mis pruebas, la primer pasada del foreach me trae un registro con hora 17, mediante el `if ($hora == $i)` al cumplirse `17 == 17` me inserta el registro al array `$data` , pero despues sigue hasta el 23 (tope del for). Luego recupera otro registro del foreach , si por ejemplo fuera el 18 , mi código funciona mal .. ya que vuelve a crear las 23 posiciones , me pisa la anterior ( la 17 con el else ) y agrega la 18 con hora 18. La idea es obtener 1 solo array del 0 al 23 , donde coincida la posición con cada hora.

Ejemplo si solo tengo registros en las horas 05 y 14, se deben crear las 24 posiciones incluyendo en la posicion 05 la hora 5 y en la 14 la hora 14 con sus respectivos datos.

Ejemplo del array :

```
array(5) {
  ["fp"]=> string(10) "2022-09-08"
  ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-09-08"
  ["hora"]=> int(1)
  ["nuevos"]=> int(0)
  ["cuenta"]=> string(5) "1 = 2"
}
array(5) {
  ["fp"]=> string(10) "2022-09-07"
  ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-09-08"
  ["hora"]=> int(2)
  ["nuevos"]=> int(3)
  ["cuenta"]=> string(5) "2 = 2"
}
array(5) {
  ["fp"]=> string(10) "2022-09-08"
  ["fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-09-08"
  ["hora"]=> int(3)
  ["nuevos"]=> int(0)
  ["cuenta"]=> string(5) "3 = 2"
}
```

Notar que en el ultimo registro , mirando "cuenta" que es un campo que agregué para verificar que hora me llega y como lo compara con $i ... debería traerme "`3 = 3`" ya que hay un dato consecutivo a la hora 3. Llega al final del for y recien ahi cambia el registro mediante el foreach ....

Comment: ¿Dónde va el cierre de llave del segundo `for`? Y si es la que está de último, entonces ¿dónde está el cierre del primer `for`? ¿Podrías poner un array de ejemplo de qué es lo que se recibe como entrada?

Comment: Me faltó copiar la llave , disculpas ! El proceso funciona, trae bien los datos pero arma mal el array ....  como explico en las aclaraciones ... cada bucle de  0 a 23 borra el bucle anterior .. la necesidad es que quede un array de  0 a 23 con las posicones correctas, ya que recibo 4 o 5 registros por dia y los demás debo completarlos tambien pero en 0, pero respetando la posicion que es == a la hora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mí me parece que lo más fácil es crear un array de largo 24 y aprovechar que el índice del array (o key) se condice con el intervalo de hora y al crear este array pones los valores default

Luego recorres $ingresos y sobrescribes los elementos que coinciden con la hora.

En teórica, es incluso más eficientes que la otra manera, ya que antes recorres el largo de ingreso x 24, de esta manera es largo de ingresos + 24

Ejemplo:

```
$data = GetArray($ingresos[0]->fecha);
foreach ($ingresos as $row)
{
    $hora = intval(substr($row->hora, 0, 2));

    if ($row->hora >= 0 && $row->hora <= 6) {
        $fecha_prod = strtotime('-1 day', strtotime($row->fecha));
        $fecha_prod = date('Y-m-d', $fecha_prod);
    }else{
        $fecha_prod = $row->fecha;
    }
    //sobrescrimos el elemento del array, que pertenece a la hora en cuestion
    $data[$row->hora] = [
        'fp' => $fecha_prod,
        'fecha' => $row->fecha,
        'hora' => $hora,
        'nuevos' => $row->ingresos
    ];

}
echo print_r($data);

//función que crar un array de 24 de largo, uno para cada hora. con valores default
function GetArray($fecha){
    $data=[];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
        $data[$i] = [
            'fp' => $fecha,
            'fecha' => $fecha,
            'hora' => $i,
            'nuevos' => 0
            ];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: excelente, pero me tira error al llamar a la funcion .  [Error] Call to undefined function App\Command\GetArray() in /var/www/html/src/Command/llamada.php on line 143 . Que podrá ser ?

Comment: Ahi probando , puse un dd($ingresos[0]->fecha); y un var_dump($ingresos[0]->fecha); para ver que llega . Me sale  [Error] Cannot use object of type Cake\ORM\Query as array . Yo traigo $ingresos que es el resultado de una consulta ORM .... no se si será el problema ..

Comment: Amigo , genial ! En vez de llamar la función puse el bucle for antes del foreach, ya que tengo una variable con la fecha del dia ... funcionó perfecto. Muchas gracias. Me cuentas como cierro esta pregunta y te valoro ?  Gracias !!

Comment: @look68 Que bueno te haya resultado!!!! Yo justo hace poco había hecho algo similar para unos gráficos, así que tenía fresca la idea.